# question about correct interpretation of sufficiency

Tags: self-study, definition, sufficient-statistics

I am currently trying to understand the concept of sufficiency and I am trying to create my own example. 
Assume that we have a statistic$$T:(\mathscr X, \mathscr A, \mathscr P) \to (\mathbb{R}^2, B^2)$$where$$\mathscr P = \left\{{\cal N}(a,1)^{\otimes 2}|a \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$ 
I think I have read that\begin{align}T:\, &(\mathbb{R}^2, B^2)\to (\mathbb{R},B)\\& (x,y) \longrightarrow x+y\end{align}is then a sufficient statistic.
We defined sufficiency the following way: $T$ is sufficient if$$\bigcap_{P \in \mathscr P}\{P(A|T)\}\neq \emptyset$$ where {$P(A|T)$} is the equivalence class of all the conditional expectations.

In other words: A statistic T is sufficienct if for every $A$ in the sample space there exists a version of the conditional probability $P(A|T) = E[1_A|T]$ such that the conditional probability does not depend on $P$

Applying this definition to the example I think that for T to be sufficient it must hold that for all $A \in \mathscr A; P, P' \in \mathscr P; x \in \mathbb{R}$ it holds that $P(A|T=t)= P'(A|T=t)$, i.e. the conditional probability is independent of the mean of the true population mean. Is this correct?

The problem is when I try to do the math it does not work out, so can you tell me whether my reasoning is correct or wheter the error is in my calculations.

I tried to show that $P(A|T=t) = P'(A|T=t)$ where $P$ is the 2d normal distribution with mean $m_1$ and $P'$ is the 2d normal distribution with mean $m_2$ by trying to show that:

$\int_{(x,y) \in A; x+y=t} \phi_{m_1,1}(x,y) d\lambda^2(x,y) = \int_{(x,y) \in A; x+y=t} \phi_{m_2,1}(x,y) d\lambda^2(x,y)$ where

$\phi_{m,1}$ is the density of the distribution $N(m,1)^{\otimes 2}$ is this the correct approach?

Comment: I do not understand the question and do not recognise this definition of sufficiency.

Comment: I do not understand what you don`t understand about the question :D
my question is (as T is sufficient) does it follow that for all $P, P' \in \mathscr P; x \in R; A \in \mathscr A P(A|T=x) =P'(A|T)$  ?

Comment: Do you have a reference to your definition of sufficiency?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is only in my script which is German. 
But I can reframe it. A statistic T is sufficienct if for every $A$ in the sample space there exists a version of the conditional probability $P(A|T) = E[1_A|T]$ such that the conditional probability does not depend on $P$